# What is the summand of $y(n) = \frac{1}{n^2}$?

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

In the book of *Difference Equations* by Peterson, it is given that

$\Delta_n (\sum_{k=a}^{n-1} y(k)) = y(n),$
where $\Delta_n y(n) = y(n+1) - y(n)$.

So, if we can find $\sum y(n)$ (where $\sum$ in there stands for the inverse operation of $\Delta$, and it is called summand of $y(n)$), we can find the partial sum of $\sum_{k=a}^{n-1} y(k)$ - it is $\sum y(n)$.

**Question:**

What is the summand of $y(n) = \frac{1}{n^2}$ ?

---

Just for those who are not familiar with this notation:

$$\sum (\Delta_n y(n)) = y(n) \quad \& \quad \Delta_n(\sum y(n)) = y(n).$$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html

Comment: @CountIblis Ok, I see now :)

Comment: @CountIblis You can answer to this question, and I can accept it.